# Why isn't the "active-work" class getting added with the onClick event?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to add an active class to some buttons in react but they're not applying. I'm not getting any errors or warnings and the syntax seems correct. What am i missing?

I have some handleEvent functions in JSX, I was expecting the "active-work" class to be applied to the span within the "work__filters" div. Everything else seems to be working. Code:

export default Works
part of CSS not getting applied:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { projectsData } from './Data'
import { projectsNav } from './Data'
import WorkItems from './WorkItems';
import "./work.css";


const Works = () => {

  const [item, setItem] = useState({ name: 'all'});
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);
  const [active, setActive] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if(item.name === "all") {
      setProjects(projectsData);
    }
    else {
      const newProjects = projectsData.filter((project) => {
        return project.category.toLowerCase() === item.name;
      });
      setProjects(newProjects);
    }
  }, [item]);

  const handleClick = (e, index) => {
    setItem({ name: e.target.textContent.toLowerCase()});
    setActive(index);
  };

  return (
    <div>
         <div className="work__filters">
            {projectsNav.map((item, index) => {
             return (
             <span 
              onClick={(e) => {
                handleClick(e, index);
              }} 
              className={`${active === index ? 'active-work' : ""}work__item`}
              key={index}>
                {item.name}
              </span>
             );
            })}
        </div>

        <div className="work__container container grid">
            {projects.map((item) => {
                return <WorkItems item={item} key={item.id}/>
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Works

//CSS not being applied 
 .active-work {
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
  }
```

Comment: You are missing a Space between the two classes. If active === index the class changes to "active-workwork__item".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks fine at first glance, except you need to put a space between `work__item` and the condition. You should see with the Devtools that the class is getting applied, but it will probably look like `class="active-workwork__item"`, hence the styling is not applied.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/sleepy-bird-975b1m?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
<span
  onClick={(e) => {
    handleClick(e, index);
  }}
  className={`${active === index ? "active-work" : ""} work__item`}
  key={index}
>
```